# how to give webcam access to LAN domain in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, lan, webcam

for some reason both Chrome and Firefox blocks WebCam access to http://192.168.66.53:81/ , and refuse to allow camera access the normal way. In Chrome i can fix it by going to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and adding http://192.168.66.53:81/ to the list, but how can i give webcam access in Firefox?

Comment: camera access, amongst many other privileged access, is only available in a secure site (i.e. https)

Comment: `media.devices.insecure.enabled` config may help though in firefox